# Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 1:') to another

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a space invader style game in visual studios xna, and after creating the basic game i have attempted to input a menu screen. In order to do this is have moved around alot of my code and put the bulk of it under case State.Playing: . The rest of it is fine but 'case' is coming up with the above error message and im simply stumped. Where should i  be looking?

```
//UPDATING PLAYING STATE 
switch (gameState)
{
    ***case*** State.Playing: 
    {
        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        int rightside = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
        int leftside = 0; 

         //moving all of the aliens 
         for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
         for (int c = 0; c < collumes; c++)
    {
```

Comment: Use `break` at the end of case

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading help on MSDN about error message first. Usually it will explain what most common reasons of error are.

Comment: That is an error where you forgot to place a 'break;' statement between cases. Not really related to XNA.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're missing some `break`s at the end of your cases. Use something like this:

```
switch (gameState)
{
    case State.Playing:
        {
            // your code
            break;
        }
    case State.WhatEver:
        {
            // your code
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Every time i add in a break; the code below becomes unreachable.

Comment: Yes, that's why you have to put it at the end of each `case`. You can't call two cases within one `switch` because `gameState` just has one value at the time it enters the `switch` statement.

Comment: Aha it worked thanks for the help!